# Sending binary data by socket between C# and Js

Tags: javascript, c#, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to send binary data between server (`C#`) application and client (js-application -- made by `WebSocket`). Connection between server and client is established and handshake is OK. Messages from client are receiving by server, but when I'm trying to send binary data to client, the event `"onmessage"` doesn't work. 
This is fragments of my `C#` code. Sending binary data in `"sendFile"` function.

```
class Listener
{
    private IPAddress ip;
    private int port;
    private TcpListener server;
    private TcpClient client;
    private NetworkStream stream;
    private bool isSuccHandshaked;

    public Listener()
    {
        ip = IPAddress.Loopback;
        port = 8080;
        server = new TcpListener(ip, port);
        isSuccHandshaked = false;
    }

    private void makeHandshake()
    {
        //...   
    }

    private String decodeMessage(Byte[] bytes)
    {
       //...
    }

    private void sendFile()
    {
        Byte[] dataToSend = File.ReadAllBytes("test.txt");
        stream.Write(datatosend, 0, datatosend.Length);
        stream.Flush();
    }

    public void startListen()
    {
        server.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server has started on {0}. Port: {1}. {2}Waiting for a connection...", ip, port, Environment.NewLine);

        client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("A client connected.");

        stream = client.GetStream();
        while (!isSuccHandshaked)
        {
            makeHandshake();
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (client.Available > 0)
            {
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[client.Available];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                String message = decodeMessage(bytes);
                sendFile();
            }
         }
    }
}
```

}

and js-code:

```js
var address = 'ws://localhost:8080';
var socket = new WebSocket( address );
socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
socket.onopen = function () {
    alert( 'handshake successfully established. May send data now...' );
    socket.send( "Aff" );
};
socket.onclose = function () {
    alert( 'connection closed' );
};
socket.onmessage = function ( evt ) {
    console.log( "Receive message!" );
    console.log( "Got ws message: " + evt.data );
}
```

Maybe there is some peculiar properties in receiving data with `WebSocket` protocol? Wich useful approaches to send `binary` data from `C#` code to `js` you can recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is not a raw TCP socket. It uses HTTP negotiation and its own framing protocol you have to comply with. If you are interested in writing your own server in C# take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server).

However if you only want to use them, you can either use the default Microsoft implementation with IIS, or you can use one of the many standalone websockets components. I maintain one named [WebSocketListener](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener).

Comment: Thank you, @vtortola, I make a correct frame, while sending and it starts work well.